# Flutter- how to post https in this format?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to send post request in Dart. 
`curl` looks like this.

```
curl -X POST "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/search" \
-F "api_key=<api_key>" \
-F "api_secret=<api_secret>" \
-F "face_token=c2fc0ad7c8da3af5a34b9c70ff764da0" \
-F "outer_id=facesetid"
```

I tried like this but error response says

> MISSING_ARGUMENTS: api_key

```
final String apiKey = API_KEY;
final String apiSecret = API_SECRET;
final String faceToken = FACE_TOKEN;
final String outerId = OUTER_ID;

final data = jsonEncode({
 'api_key': apiKey,
 'api_secret': apiSecret,
 'face_token': faceToken, 
 'outer_id': outerId
});

final http.Response request = await http.post(
  'https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/search',
  body: data,
);


final String response = request.body;
final result = json.decode(response);
print(response);
print('------------------------');
print(result);
```

What am I missing?
How can I post this correctly?

Comment: Did you try to use raw data (map) without encoding?

Comment: I thought by wrapping jsonEncode would be enough. Is it not?

Comment: I would try without jsonEncode - just final data = {
 'api_key': apiKey,
 'api_secret': apiSecret,
 'face_token': faceToken, 
 'outer_id': outerId
};

Comment: It worked thank you you made my day!

Answer (score 2):

From `man curl`

```
 -F, --form <name=content>
              (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the  Content-Type  multipart/form-data
```

https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html

> ```
> var uri = Uri.parse("http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/create");
> var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
> request.fields['user'] = 'nweiz@google.com';
> request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromFile(
>     'package',
>     new File('build/package.tar.gz'),
>     contentType: new MediaType('application', 'x-tar'));
> request.send().then((response) {
>   if (response.statusCode == 200) print("Uploaded!");
> });
> ```